# Performance issues using css transform rotate in Firefox vs Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, performance, firefox, css-transforms

I am trying to pinpoint the cause and, if possible find a fix or workaround for a performance issue I am having when updating the transform of about 200 span elements in Firefox.
In Chrome, I am able to achieve smooth 60fps, but the same example in Firefox has huge performance issues which seem to be introduced when updating the `rotate` transform of the elements.

I have reproduced the issue here:
https://codepen.io/Epz-the-bold/pen/BaGvGLx

I have tested that by removing the `rotate` transform part, Firefox keeps up with Chrome's FPS at ~55-60fps.

Does anybody have any pointers on what is causing this issue and/or possible solutions?

To clarify why I am not using CSS transitions (which would work fine in FF) and instead updating the transforms on each frame: in my original code. I am running a physics simulation to update the position and rotation of each span, so those should be managed by the physics engine to keep consistency between the DOM and the simulation.

Comment: It's simply because the FF JS engine isn't as performant as the Chrome one. You either need to 1) reduce the compute requirement (ie. less elements on the screen) 2) optimise the code (although this is unlikely to help from a quick scan of what you're doing) 3) move the logic to CSS only as this is hardware-accelerated where JS is not.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan is there something else going on, like rate-limiting? Reason for asking is that I too see a lower fps on Firefox, but neither main or graphics processor units are anywhere near saturated.

Comment: Thanks, I would think this is more a rendering/painting issue since i made sure the performance is the same when doing all calculations but not applying the transforms. I thought it was weird how much of a difference there was between FF and Chrome but you're probably right and it just comes down to individual browser quirks. It would be great if someone with knowledge of the inner workings of the render process could pinpoint what exacty is Chrome doing that Firefox doesn't to make it work so smooth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

Adding `transform-style: preserve-3d;` to the spans completely fixed the issue, I am now seeing consistent fps in both Firefox and Chrome. My guess is this forces FF to use hardware acceleration in a case where `translate3d` and `rotateZ` were not working.

### Mitigation

It seems that adding a short transition to the transform property helps mitigate this issue in Firefox, from my tests the transition duration should be higher than the average frame time or it'll cause more stuttering:

```css
transition: transform 100ms linear;
```

Comment: Interesting, so with this the system is part way through the transform when it gets changed?

Comment: That was my intention, to force Firefox to optimize the update by explicitly making it transition the values, but I have found that simply adding `transform-style: preserve-3d` to the spans accomplishes the same result without needing to resort to transitions.  I am not sure what's going on under the hood that would cause this

Comment: preserve-3d seems to force considerably more usage of the graphics processor (from 15% to 55% roughly on my laptop Windows10 on FF). The speed change is remarkable.

Answer (score 0):

Use transform: rotateZ() Instead of rotate(): Instead of using the rotate() function, try using rotateZ() with the transform property. rotateZ() is a 2D transformation and may have better performance in some cases.

```
function update() {
  spans.forEach(span => {
    span.x += span.velocity.x;
    span.y += span.velocity.y;
    span.rotation += span.velocity.x * 0.01;

    // Update only the translate transform and use rotateZ()
    span.el.style.transform = `translate3d(${span.x}px, ${span.y}px, 0) rotateZ(${span.rotation}rad)`;

    const bb = span.el.getBoundingClientRect();
    // ... Rest of the code ...
  });

  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, sadly this made no difference. My guess is translate3d is already enough to force hardware acceleration on the transforms, but since I'm updating the values each frame, FF is not able to optimize it the same way as if i was using css transitions.